# adding conditions makes query slow-oracle

Tags: database, oracle, performance

Dear Stackoverflow Nation,
this post is related to the performance of the query.
I execute a simple query  as below

**select wonum, siteid from workorder  where workorder.siteid= 'MCT'  and istask=0 
and decode(workorder.pmnum,null,workorder.reportdate,workorder.targstartdate)  >= '12-MAR-18' and
decode(workorder.pmnum,null,workorder.reportdate,workorder.targstartdate)  <= '14-MAR-18';**

It executed perfectly , took 6 sec
as i added one more condition **type ='MAINTENANCE'** ,query took 28 sec

**select wonum, siteid from workorder  where workorder.siteid= 'MCT'  and istask=0 and type ='MAINTENANCE'
and decode(workorder.pmnum,null,workorder.reportdate,workorder.targstartdate)  >= '12-MAR-18' and
decode(workorder.pmnum,null,workorder.reportdate,workorder.targstartdate)  <= '14-MAR-18';** --28.73

As I know ,I need to create an index on workorder table ,
but I am unable to figure out on which field ,I need to create an index and how it helps to run query fast.
**(Note:there is an index (ind_1 - with attributes wonum,siteid ) already in system**
kindly help.Apologize if its a basic question for PRos

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking create indexes on columns involved in `where` clause. As you described it, indexing the `type` column *might* help.

Will it really help? Who knows ... check explain plan. Collect statistics for the table so that Optimizer knows what to do (i.e. chooses the best execution plan). Then you might be able to figure out what to do.

---

Moreover, it seems that you're forcing Oracle to perform implicit conversions. Saying that

```
some_date >= '12-mar-18'
```

means that - if `some_date` column's datatype is `date` (looks like it is; otherwise you'd get wrong result) - Oracle has to convert a **string** `'12-mar-18'` into a valid `date` by applying correct format mask (such as `dd-mon-yy`). Why would you want to do that? Provide `date` value yourself!

```
some_date >= date '2018-03-12'
```

or

```
some_date >= to_date('12-mar-18', 'dd-mon-yy')
```

But beware; `mar` means "March". This query would certainly fail in my database which *speaks* Croatian, and we don't have any `mar` months here (it is `ožu`). *Perhaps* you'd rather stick to numerics here, i.e. `12-03-18`. One more note: this value is difficult to understand; what is `12`? Is it 12th day in the month, or is it December? The same goes for `03`. Therefore, **always** use values that cause no confusion, either by providing date literals (which are always in `yyyy-mm-dd` format - the one I suggested first), or use `to_date` function with appropriate format mask.